# Increase Domino database ACL max size

Tags: lotus-domino

Is there anyway to increase the Domino ACL max size? Or to extend it to allow more entries?

Basically I'm running into the upper limit at about ~550 internet users in the ACL, and would like to give more users access to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a [group document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_creatingagroup_t.html) in server's [Domino Directory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_thedominodirectory_c.html),
- add there all your internet users and
- add the group to database's ACL.